# Open Map in fancybox

Tags: fancybox

I have this:

```
$("#OpenMap").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "_Ajax.AdQuestions.php",
        data: "OpenMapID=<?php echo $_SESSION[SESSION_ADS_ID]; ?>",
        success: function(data){ $("#OpenMap").html(data); }    
    });
});
```

so now hte map will display in `<div id="">#OpenMap</div>`
How can i realize this that my Map will open it in fancybox?
eg. like this?

```
$("#OpenMap").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "_Ajax.AdQuestions.php",
        data: "OpenMapID=<?php echo $_SESSION[SESSION_ADS_ID]; ?>",
        success: function(data){ $(".fancybox").fancybox(data); }   
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$("#OpenMap").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "_Ajax.AdQuestions.php",
        data: "OpenMapID=<?php echo $_SESSION[SESSION_ADS_ID]; ?>",
        success: function(data){ 
         $.fancybox(data,{
          // fancybox API options here
         }); 
        }   
    });
});
```

Assuming that you have somewhere in your html

```
<a id="OpenMap" href="javascript:;">open map</a>
```